# Where is the repository of material.angular.io (the website) located?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

In the official website of [Material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started), it says

> material.angular.io - We build our own documentation with Angular Material!

But where is the repository located (I mean the source code of the website)? I guess it is on Github but couldn't find it.

Comment: I dont think its hosted in github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository of material.angular.io website isn't this ?

https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io
[image: capture]

Comment: This is the repository for the components, OP is asking for the code of demo website.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the website , it has a github repository link,

[image]

```
https://github.com/angular/material2
```

Comment: He is asking repository for the demo website, not the components github ?

Comment: I guess its the components, lets wait until OP responds

Comment: Thanks, @Sajeetharan. I am learning Angular and Material2, and I notice that the official website of material.angular.io is built with Material2 (and angular as well I guess). I want to know how the source code looks like for a real website built with Material2, so I wanted to ask where the source code of the website is, not the source code of the Material2 project.